# Solving second order linear PDE

Tags: calculus, analysis, partial-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the following second order linear PDE
$$
f_y(x, y) = (e^c-1)e^{-cx} - (e^c-1)e^{-cx}(f(x, y) - f_y(x,y)) - (1-e^{-c(x-1)})(f_x(x,y)-f_{x,y}(x,y)), \quad f(x, 0) = 0.
$$
I was able to solve a simpler first order approximation of it, namely,
$$
f_y(x, y) = (e^c-1)e^{-cx} - (e^c-1)e^{-cx}f(x, y) - (1-e^{-c(x-1)})f_x(x,y), \quad f(x, 0) = 0,
$$
with solution $ f(x,y) = 1-\big(\frac{e^{c(x-1)}}{e^{cy}+e^{c(x-1)}-1}\big)^{(1-e^{-c})/c} $. I'm pretty rusty with PDEs so if anyone has any good ideas, I'd love to hear them.